# Issue with SQL reserved keyword when trying to generate Spring Roo Data On Demand

Tags: sql, escaping, spring-roo, reserved-words

I am trying to generate a **Data On Demand** class for one of my entities whose class name is `Member`. However **it seems that `Member` is a reserved SQL keyword**.

So when I run the following command in the Roo shell:

```
dod --entity ~.domain.Member
```

Roo complains that Member is a reserved keyword with the following message:

> Reserved SQL keyword 'Member' is not permitted as simple type name

Does Roo allow for a way to **escape the name of my entity**? If so how?

If no, how can I circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from the Springsource team replied to me about this issue. Here is the reply:

> The dod command also allows the --permitReservedWords option to
>   overcome your issue.

Hope it can help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

What DB are you using? I don't know much about Roo, but it appears that it maps the class to a namespaced database table.  What I would suggest, although this might seem crude, is to add a prefix to your entity name, e.g. SystemMember.

Comment: Thanks Kiyomasa: I use MySQL. Changing the entity name is indeed a crude way of circumventing the problem. I am sure there must be some other way...